# Change Refresh Rate to 144Hz in Ubuntu 16.04 - "Configure crtc 0 failed" (Intel Graphics)

Tags: xorg, intel-graphics, asus, display-resolution, external-monitor

**UPDATE: Asus has responded that this hardware cannot support 144Hz. For any of you searching, sorry to bring the bad news.**

I have a new **Asus F556U** laptop and an **Asus VG248QE** monitor that I cannot get into 144Hz mode. It is stuck in 60Hz. This is causing awful eye strain and I am willing to pay/bounty whomever gets me a fix.

1.Initial `xrandr`:

```
$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.05 +  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94    59.99  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1366x768      59.79  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

So *HDMI2* is my monitor.

2.Get the modeline:

```
$ cvt 1920 1080 144
# 1920x1080 143.88 Hz (CVT) hsync: 169.35 kHz; pclk: 452.50 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_144.00"  452.50  1920 2088 2296 2672  1080 1083 1088 1177 -hsync +vsync
```

3.Create the new mode:

```
$ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_144.00"  452.50  1920 2088 2296 2672  1080 1083 1088 1177 -hsync +vsync
```

4.*Add* the new mode:

```
$ xrandr --verbose --addmode HDMI2 "1920x1080_144.00"
```

All is well up to this point... and then:

5.Output the new mode:

```
$ xrandr --output HDMI2 --mode "1920x1080_144.00"
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
```

The screen shuts off and back on after I hit enter, and then the **xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed** error comes up.

At that time, this is what gets dumped to `Xorg.0.log`:

```
==> Xorg.0.log <==
[700593.713] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1920x1080@143.9 on HDMI2 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[700593.720] (EE) intel(0): failed to set mode: Invalid argument [22]
[700593.755] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1920x1080@60.0 on HDMI2 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
```

I have also tried `xrandr --output HDMI2 --mode "1920x1080_144.00" --crtc 1` and `xrandr --output HDMI2 --mode "1920x1080_144.00" --crtc 2` and those CRTCs fail as well.

From `lspci`, I have an Intel Integrated Graphics Controller

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07)
```

Not sure if it matters, but I'm running Ubuntu Classic (Metacity window manager). I already have the `xserver-xorg-video-intel` package installed.

I have *not* messed with any `Xorg.conf` files on this machine. Maybe that is next?

This monitor *has* worked with an older NVidia graphics controller, so if I have to get a USB one, I'd be willing to do that if nothing else works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Update: Bug filed at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1621168 and it may be a hardware issue. I bought this HDMI3.0 to DVI-D cable (https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00DI89K7K) and still no luck. I am yet to hear if Asus HDMI hardware can work at higher refresh rates. 120Hz is not working either.

Answer (score 1):

Response from ASUS:

> After consulting with our team we were advised that this would not be
>   possible due to the integrated graphics on the notebook.

Closing this. If any of you are shopping for this laptop, note that it can't handle 144Hz. I'm looking at USB cards, but most likely may need to return this since 144Hz is apparently a must-have for me and my eyes and I didn't realize that!